# Does JBoss 7.x Support J2EE 5.0 and EJB 2.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-2.x

I have an application build on J2EE EJB 2.0 deployed on JBoss 5.1.0.
I want to migrate that application to JBoss 7. 
Does JBoss 7.x Support J2EE 5.0 and EJB 2.0?
If Yes, then how to Migrate Jboss 5.1.0 to JBoss 7.x?

Comment: And the question is? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Gimby Edited the Question accordingly.

Comment: EJB 2.0 was already legacy technology in JEE 5, EJB 3.0 was the standard EJB spec since then. You're actually asking how to deploy a legacy JEE 1.4 application on JBoss 7. Unless you're serious about the "migration" part, which would include changing the code to be up-to-date with the modern spec.

Comment: Thats the long term plan. As 1st I need to migrate the jboss 5 to 7 then start on migrating the code from ejb2.0 to ejb 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED 6 jun 2015**

I am migrating from jboss 4 to 7 and yes EJB 2 is supported.
Please note that class loading and JNDI names conventions have changed and you probably have to change the definition of your JNDI names and the corresponding code doing the lookup: `In AS7 there is no possibility for custom JNDI names of EJB beans and it's not planned for 7.1`.

See [this guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7) for migrating to version 7.

Note on EJB 2: run the server using the `standalone-full.xml` configuration to have your EJB entities deployed

Comment: Thanks.. Also I want to know what benefits I can get in terms of performance and usability on jboss migration..